# Building on top of Trapdoors in Vanilla?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How did this guy build seapickles and frames on top of trapdoors? Is this a mod? How do I do it? He only mentions shaderpacks/texturepacks at the end of the youtube vid, no mods

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlxb7.jpg) from around 25 mins in

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Trapdoors can be placed flush with normal blocks, either at the bottom, or the top of the block, like so:

[image]

This makes it an "applicable" surface to place items on. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s92qqkqMDXc) shows how to make Iron Trapdoor Shelves, and shows that items can be placed on trapdoors at the appropriate height.

The only issue is that Wooden Trapdoors can be opened/closed with a right-click, whereas the Iron Trapdoors need a redstone signal, so placing items on an Iron Trapdoor is just a straightforward right-click. However, you can place items on Wooden Trapdoors, by holding <kbd>L-Shift</kbd> when you place the item.

Comment: So holding L-Shift when placing the item on the wooden trapdoor.But how do you do it with an Xbox controller?

Comment: L-Shift on PC is the sneak button. I believe you achieve that by clicking in the left joystick